# RavenDB DeleteByIndex and BulkInsert in replication scenario

Tags: replication, ravendb

What I need to do is deleting an entire Collection of items and importing a new set of data.

The new set of data contains both new items and existing items (same id of the deleted items).

I need to do this on a server having Master-Master replication active with another server, so this is the scenario:

Server1 and Server2 in Master-Master replication.
I delete and bulk-insert data on Server1, the data are replicated on Server2.

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

**Step 1.**

Insert 50000 records in Server1.

```
List<Test> data = new List<Test>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 50000; i++)
{
    var t = new Test();
    t.Id = "Tests/" + i.ToString(); // NOTICE THIS
    t.Name = "Test" + i.ToString();
    t.Description = "Test nr. " + i.ToString();
    t.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hhmmssff");

    data.Add(t);
}

using (var bulkInsert = docStore.BulkInsert(options: new Raven.Abstractions.Data.BulkInsertOptions() { CheckForUpdates = true, BatchSize = 1024 }))
{
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        bulkInsert.Store(d);
    }
 }
```

The 50000 items are correctly inserted and than replicated into the Server2, so I have 50000 records in both Server1 and Server2 now.

**Step 2.**

I launch a procedure to delete the 50000 items collection in Server1 and to insert a new set of 500 items.

```
// DELETE
var op = docStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:" + "Tests" }, allowStale: false);
op.WaitForCompletion();

// INSERT
List<Test> data = new List<Test>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
{
    var t = new Test();
    t.Id = "Tests/" + i.ToString(); // NOTICE THIS, SAME IDs DELETED ABOVE
    t.Name = "Test" + i.ToString();
    t.Description = "Test nr. " + i.ToString();
    t.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hhmmssff");

    data.Add(t);
}

using (var bulkInsert = docStore.BulkInsert(options: new Raven.Abstractions.Data.BulkInsertOptions() { CheckForUpdates = true, BatchSize = 1024 }))
{
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        bulkInsert.Store(d);
    }
}
```

When this procedure starts, I correctly see in both servers that the Tests items are getting deleted, I see the documents decreasing in both servers.

When the collection in Server1 is completely deleted, the Insert procedure starts, but when this happens, the Server2 collection is not empty yet.

Let's say that when the Server1 delete operation completes, there still are 10000 items in the Server2 collection.

The Insert operation on Server1 starts now, and the inserted data begin to be replicated.

What happens in Server2 is that the Delete operation is stopped and the new 500 items are inserted, so when the procedure is complete I have 500 items on Server1 (from ID 1 to ID 500) and 10500 items on Server2.

If I delete the collection on Server1 now (from Raven Management Studio), the 500 items are deleted from the Server2, so I have no items in Server1 and 10000 items in Server2.

I also tried to combine DeleteByIndex "WaitForCompletion" setting and BulkInsert "CheckForUpdates" setting with the following results:

1.

```
DeleteByIndex.WaitForCompletion = true
BulkInsert.CheckForUpdates = true
```

Result:

the delete replication is stopped in Server2 when Insert starts on Server1 (this is the case explained above)

2.

```
DeleteByIndex.WaitForCompletion = true
BulkInsert.CheckForUpdates = false
```

Result:

the delete replication is stopped in Server2 when Insert starts on Server1 (same as above)

3.

```
DeleteByIndex.WaitForCompletion = false
BulkInsert.CheckForUpdates = true
```

Result:

I receive a concurrent modification error when Insert starts.

The delete is completed in both servers, so I have no data on both server at the end of the procedure.

4.

```
DeleteByIndex.WaitForCompletion = false
BulkInsert.CheckForUpdates = false
```

Result:

I receive an illegal duplicate key error when Insert starts,
The delete is completed in both servers, so I have no data on both server at the end of the procedure.

---

Can someone suggest the best way to manage this situation?

I recap the goal:

I need to completely delete one collection and importing new data in a Mster-Master replication scenario.
The new data can be completely new items or previously existing data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you mange to resolve it, and if so then how?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't. I had to change strategy.